# adding the arraylist value in a map

Tags: java

I have a query, I have a method in my class named abc of which return type is of arraylist as shown below

```
public List<abcinfo> getabc(String fileIdentifier)
{}
```

Now in the same class inside another method I need to add the outcome of the above method in the form of key as
shown below

```
HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        data.put("GGG", getabc(String fileIdentifier));
```

Now I am directly calling the method name as a value please advise me is it the correct way
as all the things are in same class, Please advise

Comment: Technically, there is nothing wrong with the way you are calling this.  The results of the `getabc` method will be added to the `data` `HashMap`, not the method itself ;).  There is a school of thought that you should assign the value to a temporary value first as it makes it easier to debug (as you can inspect the return result before it is added to the `HashMap`).

Comment: It is the correct way if it works as intended.
Have you tested your code?

Comment: This looks like it shouldn't compile; why is the type in the method call itself? data.put("GGG", getabc(**String** fileIdentifier));

Answer (score 1):

This will not compile as you are not exactly specifying a String object as an argument to the getabc method. Why are you specifying the type in his line? :

```
data.put("GGG", getabc(String fileIdentifier));
```

`String identifier` is not a valid argument. Pass a String argument or variable instead such as

```
data.put("GGG", getabc("ArgumentRelativeToTheContextOfYourMethod"));
```

Apart from that , there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code. (relative to what you asked)
The method or the method call being in the same class should not be a problem.

In your case , the HashMap will have an entry with key as `GGG` and value as a List returned by your getabc method.

The value however will need to be type casted to List as you have stored it as an Object

Answer (score 0):

It's correct, you can call the methode inside your class (as well as outside since it is declared as public), but on reading the Object back you will have to cast it to `List<abcinfo>`.